# $f_n$ - Measurable Functions

Tags: measure-theory

I believe I know the answer to this question but I wanted to get someones opinion on it:

let ${A_n}$ be an infinity system of sets such that $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n$ 
pairwise disjointed.
For every $n\geq1$ let $f_n:\ A_n \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function and let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ so that $f(x)=f_n(x)$ if and only if $x \in A_n $. Prove that $f$ is measurable.

Next if we reverse the claim so that $f$ is the measurable function, is $f_n$ measurable?
to be more exact, prove that it is, only if $A_n$, $n\geq1$ is a Borel set

my answer is as follows:

$x \in \mathbb R $ therefore $x \in  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n $ therefore for some given $n$, $f(x)=f_n(x)\leq a$ ,$n \geq 1$ because of its definition as a measurable function, i.e.

for every $a \in \mathbb R $ $\{ x \in A \; | \; f_n(x) < a \}$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$.

therefore $\{ x \in \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n \; | \; f(x) < a \}$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$.

the reverse is only true if for every $n$ $A_n$ is a Borel set because to reverse what i did, i.e to divide the larger set $\mathbb R$ is possible and we will get that:

$x \in \mathbb R $ therefore $x \in  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n $ therefore for some given $n$, $x \in A_n$ where $f_n(x)=f(x)\leq a$  yet we cannot say that $\{ x \in \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n \; | \; f(x) < a \}$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb A_n$.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you replace "measurable function" with "borel function"?

Comment: the definition we have is:

$f:A \to \mathbb R$ is measurable if for every $a \in \mathbb R$, the set $\{ x \in A \; | \; f(x) < a \}$ is a 
Borel set in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $A_0\subset \mathbb R$ and $A_1 = \mathbb R \setminus A_0$ two non-borel subsets of $\mathbb R$. Then take $f_0(x)=0$, $f_1(x)=1$. Both $f_0$ and $f_1$ are Borel functions (because constant functions are always borel) but the composite function is not.

Comment: so you're saying you disagree with the first part as well?